# Inject in array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, ruby-1.8.7

I am trying to do some calculation like the following. `option` is an empty hash and `aes` is an array.

```
options = {}
aes = [1,2]
test = aes.inject([]) do |array, value|
  array << value + 2
  array << value -1 if options[:calculation]  # here options[:calculation] will be nil 
end
```

I debugged and found that the value of `test` is `nil`. The output of `array << value -1 if options[:calcuation]` is `nil`, and I want to return the calculated value in `test`. For resolving this issue, I am using the code below, where `aes` is an array:

```
options = {}
aes = [1,2]
test = aes.inject([]) do |array, value|
  array << value + 2
  array << value -1 if options[:calculation]  # here options[:calculation] will be nil 
  array # I am using `array` here
end
```

Is this correct, or is there any alternate way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, result of last statement executed in a method is the return value.
If that last statement happens to be a conditional statement and does not execute, then return value is `nil`.

```
def meth
    var = nil
    10 if var # will not execute
end
p meth
#=> nil
```

Same is true for blocks as well.

In case of `Array#inject`, the return value of block given to `inject` becomes the new value of accumulator.

Since, in your case, the last statement of block does not execute due to condition being false (as `options[:calculation]` is `nil`), the accumulator value inadvertently becomes `nil`.  To avoid it returning `nil`, you had to return the value of accumulator explicitly.

You could modify your code to something like below if you don't like to use `array` as explicit return statement.

```
aes = [1,2,3,4,3,4]
options = {}
test = aes.inject([]) do |array, value|
  array + [value + 2] + (options[:calculation] ? [value - 1] : [])
end
#=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Your code is not equivalent to the OP's code: `|` removes duplicates from the array.

Comment: @Stefan You are right, my mistake.  Will use `+` instead of `|`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Enumerator#with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) instead:

```
options = {}
test = aes.each.with_object([]) do |value, array|
  array << value + 2
  array << value -1 if options[:calcuation] 
end
```

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `with_object' for #<Enumerable::Enumerator:0xb3e7fd20>

Comment: @ArvindKumar, which version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: ruby version is 1.8.7

Comment: @ArvindKumar, why are you in the stone ages? Is this a super legacy codebase or are you just using the default version of your distribution? You can try to replace `each.with_object` with `each_with_object` as I don't remember which version introduced it, but don't get your hopes too high.

Comment: As @ndn pointed out, 1.8.7 is officially [unsupported](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/) since mid 2013. If at all possible, take the bull by the horns and upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Both, `Enumerable#each_with_object` and `Enumerator#with_object` were introduced in Ruby 1.9

Comment: @Stefan, didn't know that. I have a vague memory that `each_with_object` was getting deprecated in favor of `each.with_object` so I assumed one to be older than the other. Will remove it from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are somehow misusing [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject). It is supposed to apply "a binary operation" to the elements, not to populate an array.

So, instead of writing:

```
aes = [1,2]
test = aes.inject([]) do |array, value|
  array << value + 2
  array << value - 1 if options[:calculation]
  array
end
```

I would simply write:

```
aes = [1,2]
test = []
aes.each do |value|
  test << value + 2
  test << value - 1 if options[:calculation]
end
```